# Change fixed background depending by child div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to change the background image of the parent div depending on which child div am I scrolling. I tried in the past to work with scrollY but no luck because is no responsive at all.

Basically I want when the user scroll and is on `graphic-interior-design` to have image 1when is on `graphic-architecture` to have image 2 and so on. However, I need to keep all the images fixed to the top of the long-container.

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     console.log(scrollY)
    if (window.scrollY > 9600) {
        $(".graphic-augumented-reality-page").addClass("backgroun-img-augumented-reality")
        $(".graphic-augumented-reality-page").removeClass("background-img-arhitecture")

    } 
    else{
    $(".graphic-augumented-reality-page").addClass("background-img-arhitecture")
     $(".graphic-augumented-reality-page").removeClass("backgroun-img-augumented-reality")
    }
  });
```

```css
.long-container{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png');
  background-color:white;
}
.graphic-interior-design, .graphic-arhitecture,.graphic-augumented-reality{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-container">
  <div class="graphic-interior-design"></div>
  <div class="graphic-arhitecture"></div>
  <div class="graphic-augumented-reality"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the method that I tried but I find out is not a good idea to use scrolls. Instead of ScrollY I want to change position depending by the child div scroll position .

Comment: Can you include your JS?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_bg_change_scroll check this

Comment: @CodeBug yea but it's a diffrent thing I am working with a background-image that is fixed on the parent div and I want to change it depending on child div scroll position.

Comment: @MaZoli I uploaded my old JQuery code.

Comment: your code works. I checked like this - `if (window.scrollY > 96) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
            

        }`. Perhaps where is the error location.

Comment: yea but if i have different screen sizes and more content beside these sections is not working at all that's why I am trying to replace scrollY with something to depend by the div child section

Answer (score 0):

I changed the images to colors, but I think this should help you.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var run = true;
    var color = 'blue';
    $('.long-container > div').each(function(){
        var top = $(this).position().top;

        if(window.scrollY < top && run){
            color = $(this).attr('data-image');
            $('.long-container').css('background', color );
            run = false;
        }

    })

})
```

```css
.long-container{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background: blue;
}
.graphic-interior-design, .graphic-arhitecture,.graphic-augumented-reality{
  height: 100vh;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="long-container">
  <div class="graphic-interior-design" data-image="blue"></div>
  <div class="graphic-arhitecture"  data-image="green"></div>
  <div class="graphic-augumented-reality" data-image="red"></div>
</div>
```